# In split-complex numbers, why modulus of $z=a+bj$ is $a^2-b^2$ and not $\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$?

Tags: complex-numbers, normed-spaces, split-complex-numbers

A common convention in many algebras is that modulus is

$||z||=\exp( R (\ln z))$

where R(z) is the real or scalar part.

If we use this convention for split-complex numbers, we have:

$$\ln (a+bj)=\frac12 \ln ((a+b)(a-b))+j\frac12 \ln\left(\frac{a+b}{a-b}\right)$$

The real part is $\frac12 \ln (a^2-b^2)$, so the modulus should be $\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$.

Yet, [according to Winkipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-complex_number#Conjugate,_modulus,_and_bilinear_form) it is $a^2-b^2$. Why?

Comment: Perhaps so that the modulus is a real number for all $a,b$?

Comment: @TonyK this way it does not even coincide with the absolute value of a real number.

Comment: @TonyK we don’t have to discard the radical to make the modulus real.  We can take $\sqrt{|a^2-b^2|}$.  This will also keep the modulus positive unlike $a^2-b^2$.  This leaves the question as to why the radical is discarded.

Comment: @RadialArmSaw split-complex numbers are not closed under many operations: classical modulus ($|j|=i$), logarithm ($\ln j=\frac{i\pi}2-\frac{ij\pi}2$), square root ($\sqrt{j}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}+\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right)j$), etc. In my opinion, tessarines are the way to go after swallowing complex numbers. Split-complex numbers outside of tessarines is not a good idea.